# BOOST and C++: can't seem to get polymorphism to work

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

I'm using ptr_vector to store "shapes". I'm trying to fill it with derived shape classes, such as "circles", and every time I try to downcast them I get bad cast.

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ~Shape() {};
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "shape" << std::endl; };
};

class Circle :
    public Shape
{
public:
    void print() { std::cout << "circle" << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    boost::ptr_vector<Shape> shapes;
    shapes.push_back(new Circle);

    BOOST_FOREACH(Shape shape, shapes)
    {
        Circle& tempCircle = dynamic_cast<Circle&>(shape);
        if(&tempCircle != NULL)
            tempCircle.print();
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your `shape` is an object whose type is `Shape`, and not a reference to an object whose (dynamic) type is `Circle`.

**Polymorphism only works with references or pointers**. When treating objects as *values* and copy-construct or move-construct objects of a base class from objects of a derived class, what you get is [**slicing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) (definitely not something you want).

Try this instead:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Shape& shape, shapes)
//                 ^
```

It would also make sense to use a reference to `const`, probably - since you are not going to modify the referenced object inside the loop, so:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Shape const& shape, shapes)
//                  ^^^^^^  
{
    Circle const& tempCircle = dynamic_cast<Circle const&>(shape);
    //     ^^^^^^                                  ^^^^^^

    // ...
}
```

Also notice, that C++11 has range-based `for` loops, which make `BOOST_FOREACH` kind of obsolete. So if C++11 is an option, you could write:

```
for (auto const& shape : shapes)
{
    Circle const& tempCircle = dynamic_cast<Circle const&>(shape);
    //     ^^^^^^                                  ^^^^^^

    // ...
}
```

This said, it makes sense to point out ([as Chad does in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350203/boost-and-c-cant-seem-to-get-polymorphism-to-work/17350224?noredirect=1#comment25175760_17350224)) that you do not need to perform a dynamic downcast here, since `print()` is a virtual function. When doing:

```
shape.print();
```

The function call will be dispatched to `Circle::print()` if the object referenced by `Shape` is an instance of `Circle`.

Comment: Also note, that since `print()` is a virtual function, the `dynamic_cast` is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: @Chad: Oh, right, I missed that part. I will edit, thank you :)

Comment: @Chad: when i use for(auto const& shape : shapes), when i try to call shape.print(), it says that the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function :(

Comment: @dubesinhower: You should make `print()` a `const` member function (so `void print() const { ... }`), since it does not need to alter the state of the object it is invoked on

Answer (score 0):

Also, you're not using dynamic_cast correctly. If you dynamic_cast a reference, and the object does not actually belong to the class you're casting it to, then the cast throws `std::bad_cast`. It does not return null because there's no such thing as a reference with a null address. So here's the correct way:

```
Circle* tempCircle = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(&shape);
if(tempCircle != NULL)
    tempCircle->print();
```

(You can actually have a reference `r` with `&r == NULL`, but only after dereferencing a null pointer, which has undefined behavior.)